# Pushing Data to UIViewController from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am having a pretty big issue with pushing data from my `UITableView` to 5 labels on my `UIViewController`. I have an app that you press a "climb" and depending on what climb you choose, different specs will appear when you are pushed to the `UIViewController`. Right now it just goes to a blank screen, I have my labels hooked up to my class and all just unsure how to get tit to transfer different info to each label, depending on what climb is chosen. I will post my code now:

**`FourthTableViewController.h`:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FourthTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sectionName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

**`FourthTableViewController.m`:**

```
#import "FourthTableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *NewBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:NewBackButton];

self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:183/255.0 green:207/255.0 blue:85/255.0 alpha:0.5];

//populating arrays
NSDictionary *dict = @{/*Moss Rock Sections*/@"Grass Man":@[@"Tesseract", @"Chalky Dreams", 
@"Aristocratic Nose", @"Bee Stings", @"Recovery Run Traverse", @"Heel Shock", @"Fourth of July", 
@"No Sack", @"Poop Dreams", @"Hoop Dreams", @"Grass Man Traverse", @"Mikey Likes It", @"Just 
Throw", @"Rapture", @"Caveman Hunt", @"Batman Dyno", @"Waiting Line", @"Petrified Lady 
(project)", @"Up and Over", @"Rocker", @"Heart", @"Left Ventricle", @"Poison Ivey", @"Snake 
Eyes", @"Rattle", @"Shape Shifter", @"Road to Nowhere", @"Beef It", @"Switchback", @"Pine 
Phriend", @"Hanging Out", @"Warp Hole", @"Deet", @"Mosquito Bites"], @"Lost Roof": @[@"I'll 
Tumble for Ya", @"Snoopy's House", @"Treelee", @"Lost Roof Problem"], @"Ozzy":@[@"Clark Direct", 
@"Long Shot", @"Pile", @"Revolver", @"The Bomb", @"Suntoucher", @"A Young One", 
@"Nebuchadnezzar's Dream", @"Profanity", @"Godfather", @"Re-Ignition", @"Rancid", @"Tree 
Problem", @"Scrutinzier", @"Little Big Horn", @"Cheese is Good", @"Maybe Later", @"Double 
Clutch", @"A.X Variation", @"Salute", @"Ozzy Crack", @"Adam's Slab", @"Orange Streak", @"Tommy 
H", @"Vast Understatement", @"Super Crimp", @"Big Ben", @"Fat Cut", @"It Burns!", @"The Trip", 
@"Tesseract"]/*End Moss Rock Sections*/, @"Colorado Section 1":@[@"Colorado Climb 1", @"Colorado 
Climb 2", @"Colorado Climb 3"]};

climbs = dict[self.sectionName];

[self.objects addObjectsFromArray:climbs];
}
```

**`DetailViewController.h`:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *detailLabelContents;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gradeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *coordinatesLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rockLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *difficultyLabel;


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *climbName;

@end
```

**`DetailViewController.m`:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *NewBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:NewBackButton];

//populating arrays
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Alabama Climb 1":@[@"Alabama Spec 1", @"Alabama Spec 2", @"Alabama Spec 
3"], @"Georgia Climb 1": @[@"Georgia Spec 1", @"Georgia Spec 2", @"Georgia Spec 3"], @"Tennessee 
Climb 1":@[@"Tennessee Spec 1", @"Tennessee Spec 2", @"Tennessee Spec 3"], @"Colorado Climb 
1":@[@"Colorado Spec 1", @"Colorado Spec 2", @"Colorado Spec 3"]};

specs = dict[self.climbName];

self.detailLabel.text = self.detailLabelContents;
}
```

In summary, I would like for when a climb is chosen that climbs specs appear in the 5 labels on the `UIViewController` it is pushed to, when another climb is chosen that climbs specs show up. (I am assuming it will be a giant if/else statement).

Any advice or constructive criticism will be much appreciated, I know my syntax is not perfect, I am very new to this language.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the label text anywhere?

Comment: I am not, that is my question, I am unsure of how to do it to accomplish what I want and where to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your label text, you have to pass the `NSString` to the next `view controller`, then set it in your `viewDidLoad`.

So make 5 properties which correspond to your label, and pass the data like you did with the `climbName` `NSString` (in your `prepareForSegue` method).

To set the label text, do this in your `viewDidLoad` of your `destination view controller`

```
self.titleLabel.text = self.myStringThatIPassed;
```

Comment: Right, so would I just make a giant if else statement in my "viewDidLoad" in my DVC that says when this climb is chosen set the labels to this text?

Comment: Im sorry, I just can't get my head wrapped around this concept, could you just show me one example with the code I provided? I could then look at it and better understand and visualize it. Just how one climb being pressed could set the 5 labels to specific text

Comment: Not really, you determine what data or strings to pass in your prepareForSegue.

Comment: And yeah sure, give me a moment

Comment: Can you tell me where you get the title, difficulty, and such?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54001/discussion-between-nlee918-and-javageek).

Comment: could I ask for your help on another issue I am having?